# Equi-order in pressure correction schme of Navier-Stokes equation

Tags: finite-element, navier-stokes

I am wondering if there is an stabilized equi-order scheme in pressure correction scheme in solving Navier-Stokes equation? Usually P2-P1 element combination is used to solve NS equation, and a PSPG stabilizing term could be added if NS equation is solved by P1-P1 element in a coupled way. My question is, is there a conterpart in pressure correction equation?